# How to test an Angular app?

Tags: angularjs

For simple application such as just a "Hello World" where do I write tests.

I have created a plnkr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/M0GAIE837G3s1vNwTyK8?p=info

Now this is a very simple plnkr, which does nothing but display Hello World. 
Now if I want to write a test for this Application i.e for MainCtrl.. where do I plug it in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run test with Angular-Karma-Jasmine:

1. You need to install [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/), karma runs on top of node
2. You need to install karma from [Node Packaged Modules](https://npmjs.org/) from your command window execute:

   ```
   npm install -g karma
   ```
3. If you plan to run this with Chrome and Firefox and you are running this on windows you need to add 2 [environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
   CHROME_BIN = [Crome installation path/chrome.exe]
   FIREFOX_BIN =[Firefox installation path/firefox.exe]
```

4. Go back to your project folder using the command window once there you can execute:

```
karma init
```

Just hit enter until it finishes; bottom line this will create a file named:

```
karma.config.js
```

In my project this file looks like this, yours probably will include some helpful comments on the different settings:

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
      config.set({    
        basePath: '',    
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],    
        files: [
          '../app/*.js',
          '../app/lib/angular.js',
          '../app/lib/angular-route.min.js',
          '../app/lib/angular-mocks.js',         
          '../app/app.js',
          'controllers/*.js',
          'services/*.js',
        ],    
        exclude: [
        ],    
        reporters: ['progress'],    
        port: 9876,    
        colors: true,    
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,    
        autoWatch: true,    
        browsers: ['Chrome','Firefox'],
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        singleRun: false
      });
    };
```

**Important:** make sure you included angular-mocks in your configuration, the `inject` function is on that module.

5. Go back to your command window, navigate where your `karma.config.js` file is and and execute:

```
karma start
```

At this point you will be good to go to start writing tests with jasmine.

a simple jasmine test for your controller will be:

```
describe('MainCtrl', function() {
    var $scope, $rootScope, createController;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();


    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

        createController = function() {
            return $controller('MainCtrl', {
                '$scope': $scope
            });
        };
    }));

    it('should have a...', function() {
        var controller = createController();
// do your testing here...

    });
});
```